# Workbench application development using Eclipse RCP :: How rich can it get?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-rcp

Like the subject reads:

How much good-looking UIs can be built using Eclipse RCP? 
Can they be built to look as good as the app screen below?

Or, lets just define **good** being: support for rounded borders, gradient backgrounds, rich text, true type fonts and all those stuff that applies to modern rich UI look and feels.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mimblog.de](http://mimblog.de/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/mozenda-web-agent-builder.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Where the definition of good being: support for rounded borders, gradient backgrounds, rich text, true type fonts and all those stuff that applies to modern rich UI look and feels.

Comment: you can (and should) edit your question to include those details instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upcoming **[eclipse e4](https://www.eclipse.org/e4/)** will support for eclipse itself, or RCP applications, all sort of skins [including gradient-based ones](https://toedter.com/2009/06/16/e4-css-styling-more-fun-with-radial-gradients/).

[image]
<sub>(source: [toedter.com](http://www.toedter.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/contacts-dark-gradients-small-2.png))</sub>

---

With its new themes based on CSS like Declarative Syntax, it is really simple to contribute to a rich interface... even the [latest 3.6 builds can make use of the CSS themeing support](https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2010/04/26/a-week-at-e4-themeing-in-e4/).

> An example CSS-File could look like this:

```
.h2 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20pt;
}

.container {
    background-color: gradient radial #575757 #101010 60%;
}
```

> and the Java-Code to use it

```
final Composite p = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
p.setData(CSS_CLASS_KEY, "container");
p.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

Label l = new Label(p, SWT.NONE);
l.setData(CSS_CLASS_KEY, "h2");
l.setText("This is a headline");
l.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.DEFAULT, false, false, 2, 1));

engine.applyStyles(p, true); // Apply the CSS-Instructions of the current active theme
```

The last line applies the current theme CSS-Information on all elements below the given widget.

> Switching between themes is quite easy using:

```
engine.setTheme("org.eclipse.e4.demo.contacts.dark");
```

> Which makes the 3.x ViewPart look like this with a radial black gradient:

[image]

> or a bright one:

[image]

Comment: so this just means, there is no support as of now? are there any open source tools that would enable eclipse RCP for this kind of look and feel?

Comment: @Jay: I just completed my answer to show how "current" (actually Helios Eclispe3.6 only) versions of Eclipse can already used CSS-based themes.

Comment: Thank You. Just what I was looking for - looks great. I will try out borders and other stuff.